# remote server does not like whatsapi script line

Tags: php, class, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have just resolved one whatsapi issue on this forum and now am confronted with another one.

I am running scripts by calling the classes in whatsprot.class.php. I can run all scripts on my local machine like a charm. But remote server  doesn't like the a certain line in my script and refuses to go beyond that;

My script is;

```
require "src\whatsprot.class.php";

$username = "91xxxxxxxxxxx"; //Mobile Phone prefixed with country code so for india it will be 91xxxxxxxx
    $password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$identity = strtolower(urlencode(sha1($username, true)));

$w = new WhatsProt($username, $identity, 'WhatsApp Messaging', true);
```

The line that my remote server doesn't cross is;

```
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $identity, 'WhatsApp Messaging', true);
```

I definitely am an amateur. So do let me know what other info would be required to demystify this issue...

Comment: Could you add the error message of your server?

Comment: please show us your error message

Comment: sorry, @seb , GottZ.. not able to get error log of server as there is some cpanel issue for all my domains on the server and cannot see the logs... or anything on cpanel for that matter ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally the error logs told me that there was some path issue in the libraries. When I moved my executing file into the "src' directory where whatsprot.class.php was located, voilà the script started working !